# Creating an insert query (error on foreign key constraint)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert, foreign-keys

I want to move data from one database's table to another database's table. I am getting a foreign key error. How can I insert all the data which is valid except those rows who don't have a foreign key?

My query is :

```
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT City ON

  INSERT INTO City ([cityid],[city],[country],[state],[cityinfo]
  ,[enabled],[countryid],[citycode],[stateid],[latitude],[longitude])
  SELECT [cityid],[city],[country],[state],[cityinfo]
  ,[enabled],[countryid],[citycode],[stateid],[latitude],[longitude]
  FROM TD.DBo.City
```

getting this error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__city__countryid__3E52440B". The conflict occurred in database "schoolHigher", table "dbo.country", column 'countryId'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` the other database's table with the `country` table. Only those records with an existing country will get selected.

Note: you should check that the corresponding countryid's in both databases match.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT City ON

INSERT INTO City (
    [cityid]
    ,[city]
    ,[country]
    ,[state]
    ,[cityinfo]
    ,[enabled]
    ,[countryid]
    ,[citycode]
    ,[stateid]
    ,[latitude]
    ,[longitude])
SELECT  ct.[cityid]
        ,ct.[city]
        ,ct.[country]
        ,ct.[state]
        ,ct.[cityinfo]
        ,ct.[enabled]
        ,ct.[countryid]
        ,ct.[citycode]
        ,ct.[stateid]
        ,ct.[latitude]
        ,ct.[longitude]
FROM  TD.DBo.City ct
      INNER JOIN dbo.Country cnt ON cnt.CountryID = ct.CountryID
```

Comment: Don't mention it, also don't forget to check both your country tables.